# Better deepcopy in java?

Tags: java, serialization, java-8, deserialization, deep-copy

Is there any faster deep copy technique available in java to deep copy an object? My classes implement Serializable

As for now, I am using :

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class ObjectCloner {
    // so that nobody can accidentally create an ObjectCloner object
    private ObjectCloner() {
    }

    // returns a deep copy of an object
    @MetricsLogger(enableSuccessMetrics = true)
    static public Object deepCopy(Object oldObj) throws Exception {

        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = null;
        try {
            if (oldObj != null) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream =  new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
                // serialize and pass the object
                outputStream.writeObject(oldObj);
                outputStream.flush();

                ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
                objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(bin);
                // return the new object
                return objectInputStream.readObject();

            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RankingPolicyException("Exception while cloning : ", e);
        } finally {
            if (outputStream != null && objectInputStream != null) {
                objectInputStream.close();
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine but it is pretty slow performance wise. Please let me know if there is a way better way to do deep-copy.

Comment: I don't know about the serialization, but if you are writing `java-8`, you should be using [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: Generally in Java, you'd want to write custom deep copy logic on a per-class basis. Certain things aren't going to be Serializable, and ObjectOutputStream is just going to serialize a null wherever it finds one. This will lead to difficult-to-troubleshoot bugs downstream if you're not very careful. Furthermore, some objects are immutable (like String) and the reference can be safely shared between two objects without making a full copy.

Comment: 1) if objects are part of your codebase, you can write a constructor for each of your objects which takes the object containing data as input. depending upon object class, you can invoke the constructor and get the copy. 2) if not, then you'd need to write custom deep copy for each type of object. Eg, to get deep copy of HashMap, you'd iterate over keys and add key with value to a new HashMap.

Comment: @Andrew Rueckert: `ObjectOutputStream` throws an exception, if it encounters an object that is not serializable, it does *not* substitute it with `null`. If you encounter such a behavior, it’s already a customized `writeObject` method that is responsible.

Comment: I’d generally question the need for deep-copies of objects. If you encounter such a need, you surely have already bigger design issues you should fix instead.